# Having problems using percentages passed in through ("input").val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

To be honest, I think I just have to convert the values to integers, but I've tried a bunch of things and keep getting 'NaN' or something along the lines of 'cannot use this action on an object'.  I want to do things like use replace to remove the % or simply apply math to it.  I have tried String and parseInt() to try to convert but just get NaN.

This example gives me an alert box that says "10%" or "20%"...whatever the user types in

```
thisInvoiceDiscount = $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val(); 
percentPresent = thisInvoiceDiscount.indexOf("%"); 
if (percentPresent == "-1") { 
} 
else { 
  alert (thisInvoiceDiscount);
  //I can't seem to do anything with thisInvoiceDiscount here
}
```

UPDATE: Using the 1st response:

```
thisInvoiceDiscount = $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val();
var numberOnly = $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val().replace(/\D/g, '');
percentPresent = thisInvoiceDiscount.indexOf("%");
if (percentPresent == "-1") {
}
else {
    var integerValue =  parseInt(numberOnly, 10);
    alert (integerValue);
}
```

Comment: You should use `var` when you declare variables.

Comment: but sometimes i need them globally, outside this function

Comment: You mixed the two code, replace it. My code should take care of all, it will remove the `%` suffix, you don't need to check for it's index.

Comment: @gdoron ah, but I need to check for the %, because the user can enter a dollar amount or a %...i need to detect which it is...I just removed the extra code because it wasn't relevant, but there are things in if (percentPresent == "-1") {
}, for example

Comment: @gdoron right, but I still need to detect whether its a % or number before I remove the "%" symbol

Comment: See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RQDtH/1/). Is it o.k. now? just change in the textbox from `$` to `%` and see what does it do.

Comment: @gdoron that definately works now, thank you...any idea why the original code didn't work?

Comment: You probably had a typo or something, it should work, (slow but words...) If you really want to know what was it, try reproduce it in a jsfiddle, I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: sounds good...I'm actually seeing some success with the same code in jsfiddle, oddly enough.  Oh well, thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var numberOnly = 
        $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val().replace(/\D/g, '');
```

This will strip out every non digit char from the string.

```
var integerValue =  parseInt(numberOnly, 10);
```

This will parse the string to an integer.

Of course you can make the `regex` more specific targeting the `%` sign:

```
var numberOnly = 
        $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val().replace(/%/, '');
```

Or this `regex` to remove `%` only if it's the last char in the string:

```
var numberOnly = 
        $("#clientSearchInvoiceDiscountTextbox").val().replace(/%$/, '');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RQDtH/1/) <sub>(based on the update)</sub>

---

**Note that**, you better compare to an int number than a string when comparing to an `indexOf` result, it will add a (very small...)boost to your code and the code won't brake if you compare with `===`

Comment: or `parseFloat()` if percentages are not integers.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'indexOf'

Comment: @epascarello. You're right, be he wrote `integer` in the question. anyway your comment will stay... thanks